# How to find a TreeView node by its value

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding

I am working on a genealogy application and I plan to store references to each family member in an XML document. I would like to read this document and display it as a treeview in my application and then use it to display a family member elsewhere in the application. What I need to do is find a specific value in the node tree (each member will have a unique value). How would I find this value? Could you please give me a hand here, I am quite new to node editing. TY.

BTW, below is my XAML code:

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <Binding XPath="child::*" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlDataProvider"></XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView Margin="0,24,0,143"
              Name="treeView1"
              Background="AliceBlue"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlDataProvider}, XPath=*}"
              ItemTemplate= "{StaticResource NodeTemplate}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed that the unique value is the `id` attribute. So the code will look so:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = FindItemById(treeView1.Items.Cast<XmlElement>(), "2.1");
        if (item != null)
        {
            //Do something...
            //for example, item.SetAttribute("name", "test");

            //But this code will not work if the item isn't visible
            //var container = treeView1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        }
    }

    public XmlElement FindItemById(IEnumerable<XmlElement> items, string id)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.HasAttribute("id") && item.GetAttribute("id") == id)
                return item;
            var childItemsResult = FindItemById(item.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlElement>(), id);
            if (childItemsResult != null)
                return childItemsResult;
        }

        return null;      
    }
```

If your xml file has a different attribute as an identifier, change this line accordingly: `item.HasAttribute("id") && item.GetAttribute("id")`.

The final result will be the `XmlElement` object. But it isn't easy to retrieve the container because of the algorithm of generation of treeview items. Anyway, if you have a specific question - I can help to build a correct architecture.

Comment: 1) You don't need to use both `HasAttribute` and `GetAttribute`; `GetAttribute` returns the empty string if the attribute doesn't exist.  2) You should use XPath instead of writing recursive functions that iterate over DOM properties - `XmlElement elm = doc.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='2.1']") as XmlElement` accomplishes  the same thing in a single line of code.  3) You don't need to use code-behind; the only thing you're doing here that you can't do through binding, finding the item container, is something that almost certainly doesn't need to be done in a properly-written WPF application.

Comment: @Robert Rossney Ok, XPath works, but only for a document instead of the actual items source. Next, code behind is absolutely necessary because to find item != to select item. About properly-written applications: the `TreeView` control doesn't allow even two way binding to the `SelectedItem` property. This control have more problems and require more hacks than any other control.

Comment: XPath won't work on the items source directly, but since the items source is an `XmlDataProvider`, it'll work on the `Document` property.  And yes, `TreeView.SelectedItem` is read-only.  If the question is "how do I programatically select a `TreeView` item in the UI, given the object it's bound to, and make sure it's scrolled into view?" I'd like to know the answer myself, if it has one.

Comment: @Robert Rossney When I launched the application in debug mode, the `ItemsSource` property of the `TreeView` had the `MS.Internal.Data.XmlDataCollection` type. To receive the document, it is necessary either to get the first item or to retrieve the provider from the collection of resources. About selecting an item, I used binding of the `IsExpanded` and `IsSelected` properties to corresponding properties of a view model, but it looks as dirty hack.

Comment: It looks like a dirty hack, but it has a reasonable foundation.  Given that any expandable node in the `TreeView` can be collapsed and its child nodes virtualized, if you're trying to find the `TreeViewItem` for a given bound object, it - and its ancestors - may not exist yet.  The only way for you to find it is to navigate to it from the root down, because that forces the item to actually exist.  To implement this, I'd create the navigate-to-item method in the view, and have the view model raise an event to when it needed to be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a selectable `ItemsControl` to an `XmlDataProvider`, the `SelectedItem` contains the `XmlNode` that's the binding source for the item.  If you set that as the `DataContext` for a view, you can then display (or edit) anything that can be selected via XPath from that node.

So in the below example, which you can paste into Kaxaml, the `ContentControl`'s `DataContext` is bound to the `SelectedItem` on the `TreeView`.  Controls placed inside it can then bind to any XML nodes that are findable via XPath.

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data" XPath="/Data">
      <x:XData>
        <Data xmlns="">
          <Person Name="Becky">
            <Person Name="Stephen">
              <Person Name="Tom"/>
              <Person Name="Susannah"/>
            </Person>
            <Person Name="Deborah">
              <Person Name="Geoffrey"/>
              <Person Name="Christopher"/>
            </Person>
          </Person>
        </Data>
      </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
  </Page.Resources>
  <Grid> 
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TreeView x:Name="MyTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data}, XPath=*}">
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>
          <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0">Parent:</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="1">Children:</Label>

        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
      </Grid>
    </ContentControl>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

You have to use a `ContentControl` and set the `DataContext`.  That's the only actual trick here.  The reason you have to do this:  if you tried to just bind a `TextBlock`, say, you'd end up with a control like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyTreeView, Path=SelectedItem, XPath=@Name}"/>
```

and you can't use `Path` and `XPath` in the same binding.